# How can I upload music from an iPhone to a PC without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, software-recommendation, data-synchronization, windows

I am looking for an app that will let me transfer media from iPhone 5 to a PC without iTunes sync.

It has 3 atributes that I like:

- works on any Windows
- upload media with no iTunes sync
- multiple iOS management

Comment: Duplicate post might be the wrong direction of sync. @bmike

Answer (score 0):

You probably get frustrated because of the lengthy process to sync your library with iTunes. But **you don’t have to** sync the media.

Instead of syncing media, you can manually manage the music and videos. Apple has written [a step by step guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1535?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for this option.